# VBA Property Let, not accepting value passed

Tags: excel, vba

```
'CLASS PROPERTY CODE
Public Property Let setCode_ID(ByVal vCode_ID As String)
    Code_ID = vCode_ID
End Property

For Each Cell In WS_CostCode.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(fRow, 1)) 'COLUMN OF CODE_ID
    Set CostCodeItem = New Cost_CodeCL
    CostCodeItem.setCode_ID = "code id" 'WS_CostCode.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column) 'SET CODE_ID 'SET CODE_ID
    CostCodeItem.setCode_Description = "code desc" 'WS_CostCode.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column + 1) 'SET CODE_DESCRIPTION
    CostCodeItem.setCode_Category = "code category" 'WS_CostCode.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column + 2) 'SET CODE_CATEGORY

    uKey = CostCodeItem.getCode_ID
    Debug.Print CostCodeItem.getCode_ID
    CostCodeColl.Add CostCodeItem, CostCodeItem.getCode_ID
Next Cell
```

My pproperty "vCode" should show whatever string I pass within the For Each Loop, but when it runs, as soon as it access the Property Let and I step through it to make sure my string is being passed, it shows as "", instead of whatever I am passing.

I used the EXACT same code in another class and it works perfectly as expected. Why is this not behaving properly.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the rest of the property code? ie. the field and `getCode_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel like such a newb! Sorry for waisting anyone's time. I guess I have been looking at way to much code and haven't gotten enough rest. I had one of my formulas written backwards by accident.

Thanks again.